# Postgresql: cannot get result using sub-query at FROM ... place

Tags: postgresql

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get aggregated data for all unique combinations of `sendercompid`, `targetcompid`, `msgtype`  through all tables in inner SQL.

I expect to have from 20mil to 40mil unique rows in resulting output.

I cannot succeed in running next query on Postgresql 8.3.13:

```
SELECT 
    sendercompid, targetcompid, count(msgtype), msgtype 
FROM 
    (SELECT table_name 
     FROM information_schema.tables 
     WHERE table_catalog = 'test' 
       AND table_schema = 'msg' 
       AND (table_name like 'fix_aee_20121214%') OR 
           (table_name like 'fix_aee2_20121214%')
   ) 
WHERE 
    (sendercompid LIKE '%201%') OR 
    (targetcompid LIKE '%201%') 
GROUP BY 
    sendercompid, targetcompid, msgtype ;
```

If this select is being split on 2 : outer and inner, then :
inner will provide list of tables  and outer will do select and grouping from each table .

If I run those two SQLs as one, I have an alias error from pgsql db

> ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias

I tried use alias, but this error not disappear.

Any thoughts what I am missing there?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot define the "from" part dynamically, **all** table names involved in a query must be known before the statement is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FROM doesn't work the way you think it does.  A sub-select works like any other query: it produces a set of rows.  The outer SELECT works with those rows as though they were a table.  There's no special magic beyond that; it has no idea that the values you're returning are table names, and won't treat them as such.

You can probably accomplish what you want using the catalog tables, but that would be complicated and hack-y.

Since your sub-tables appear to be date-based partitions, I think what you really want to use is the partitioning support built into Postgres, described [in these docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/ddl-partitioning.html).  Essentially your partitions inherit from a parent table, and you set up range constraints on each child.  When you query from the parent table with constraint_exclusion enabled, Postgres automatically selects the appropriate partition.

Comment: many thanks for detailed answer. Unfortunately , i do not have partitioning set up, and i cannot do so. DB is being filled with aplication out of my responsibility, so i can only read from tables and that is all. Indeed all tables in FROM clause are the same by data structure and differ only with date in name, so they could be childs of one master table. Unfortunatelly it is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can "run" such query using dynamic SQL. The idea - to form the proper query with table name as string inside PL\pgSQL procedure and `EXECUTE` it. Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.function1 (
)
RETURNS TABLE (
  "field1" NUMERIC,
  "field2" NUMERIC,
  ...
) AS
$body$
BEGIN
 RETURN EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM '|| (SELECT table_name from information_schema.tables 
              where table_catalog = 'test' AND 
                    table_schema='msg' AND
                    (table_name like 'fix_aee_20121214%') OR 
                    (table_name like 'fix_aee2_20121214%')); 
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Then use something like:

```
SELECT sendercompid, targetcompid, count(msgtype), msgtype 
       FROM  function1
       WHERE (sendercompid LIKE '%201%') OR 
             (targetcompid LIKE '%201%') 
       GROUP BY sendercompid, targetcompid, msgtype ;
```

Or you can create function with full query and some parameters to build `WHERE` clause.

Details: [EXECUTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-execute.html),

Comment: Thanks Igor. Unfortunately this  not work for me, i need part with "table_name like" dynamic. SO i will need to create new procedure for each date. This  creates additional overhead.

Comment: @Daniel No need to create a procedures for every date. Just pass the date as a parameter to the function. Something like `table_name like 'fix_aee_'||to_char(date_param,'yyyymmdd')||'%'`

Comment: @Daniel Then `SELECT * FROM function_name(CURRENT_DATE)`

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a concept then:

1. `ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias`.
2. There's is no information where columns `sendercompid, targetcompid, count(msgtype), msgtype` are come from.

   SELECT sendercompid, targetcompid, count(msgtype), msgtype from (
      SELECT table_name from information_schema.tables 
             where table_catalog = 'test' AND 
                   table_schema='msg' AND
                   (table_name like 'fix_aee_20121214%') OR 
                   (table_name like 'fix_aee2_20121214%')
      ) a
      WHERE (sendercompid LIKE '%201%') OR 
            (targetcompid LIKE '%201%') 
      GROUP BY sendercompid, targetcompid, msgtype ;

Answer (score -1):

Use alias for subquery. Better you alias for all tables to avoid confusion.